# Какой термин подходит для определения главной части условного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Вопрос по терминологии.

Переводя арабскую грамматику, затруднился с переводом терминов.

Возьмем условное предложение или предложение времени.

Например:

1) Если пойдет дождь, то я не выйду из дома.
Предложение состоит из двух частей: условная часть - Если пойдет дождь, а вторая часть на арабском называется "ответ условия".
Или предложение времени:
2) Когда пойдет дождь, я выйду из дома.
Первая часть - это условие времени, а вторая часть на арабском тоже называется "ответ времени".
3) Кто послушал, молодец.
Вторая часть (молодец) на арабском тоже называется термином "ответ".

Вопрос состоит в том, как на русском называется этот термин "ответ".

Answer (score 2):

"Если пойдет дождь, то я не выйду из дома".

Грамматическое значение СПП - это смысловые отношения между предикативными частями (условные, временные и др.). Например, в СПП с придаточным условным придаточная часть выражает условие, при реализации которого может осуществиться  ситуация главной части.

При переводе для слова "ответ" самым близким по значению  можно считать слово "реализация", например: условие - реализация условия, время - реализация времени.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Посмотрел, что такое тема-рема. Мне показалось, что это более общие понятия, которые касаются всех видов членения. Применительно к моему вопросу их нужно сузить как-то. А вот термин "реализация" мне понравился. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо отметить, что арабский и русский языки - два разных языка: следовательно, и грамматика у них разная. В русском языке предложения делятся на тему и рему (актуальное членение предложения). ***Тема*** -  (исходный пункт высказывания) - это та часть высказывания, которая самая известная слушателю/читателю/ и т.п., одним словом, получателю этого высказывания.
***Рема (ядро)*** - это та часть высказывания, которая новая и неизвестная получателю. Ядром она называется потому, что именно ради этой части высказывания само это высказывание и порождается.
В вашем предложении тема - эта условная часть, рема - главное предложение.